# SQL function which returns true/false depending on success of insert query

Tags: postgresql, insert

I want to write a SQL function which returns `true` if a certain `INSERT` inserted a row and `false` if no row was inserted. In this use case, we know that at most one row can be inserted.

I came up with the following solution:

```
create function test() returns boolean as
$$
    with
    dummy as
    (
        insert into    ...
        select         ...
        from           ...
        where          ... -- this will limit to at most one row
        returning      true
    )
    select exists(select true from dummy);
$$
language sql volatile;
```

This seems to work fine, but it is rather clumsy and verbose, in my opinion. Is there something better possible?

I first wanted to write the following:

```
create function test() returns boolean as
$$
    insert into    ...
    select         ...
    from           ...
    where          ...
    returning      true;
$$
language sql volatile;
```

The problem now is that not `false` but `null` is returned when no row was inserted.

Comment: How about `COALESCE(test(), FALSE)`?

Comment: @dezso I would rather not solve this at the caller side of the function, as this is easily forgotten. Also, I would say that we should not have to expect a `null` from a function that returns a boolean.

Comment: Is language [plpgsql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) acceptable ?

Comment: @SahapAsci Is it possible to do this cleaner with pure SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way with little noise in the code:

```
create function test()
  returns boolean as
$$
   WITH ins AS (
      insert into    ...
      select         ...
      from           ...
      where          ...
      returning      true
      )
   SELECT true FROM ins
   UNION ALL SELECT false;
$$
language sql volatile;
```

The function, being declared as `returns boolean` (and not `returns setof boolean`) returns only the first row. If no `INSERT` happens, the first (and only) row delivers `false`.

Or, a shorter version of your first variant:

```
...
   WITH ins AS (
      insert into    ...
      )
   SELECT EXISTS(TABLE ins)
...
```

See:

- [Is there a shortcut for SELECT * FROM?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30276023/939860)

Related (with alternatives):

- [How to return a value from a function if no value is found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29294021/939860)

Quoting [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html) to clarify the behavior of SQL functions:

> SQL functions execute an arbitrary list of SQL statements, returning
>   the result of the last query in the list. In the simple (non-set)
>   case, **the first row of the last query's result will be returned**. (Bear
>   in mind that “the first row” of a multirow result is not well-defined
>   unless you use `ORDER BY`.) **If the last query happens to return no rows
>   at all, the null value will be returned.**

Bold emphasis mine.

Note: the above is a *single* query. And we don't need `ORDER BY`, since a plain `UNION ALL` without more operations in the outer query level simply appends the resulting row to the set in last position.